# react navigation how to change language of bottom tabs

Tags: react-native, expo

MainTabNavigator.js

```
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
const ExploreStack = createStackNavigator({
    Explore: ExploreScreen,
});
ExploreStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'explore',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <MyTabBarIcon style={{width:22, height:21}} name={'explore'} focused ={focused} />
    ),
};
const CarStack = createStackNavigator({
    CarStack: CarScreen,
});

CarStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'car',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <MyTabBarIcon style={{width:39, height:19}} name={'car'} focused ={focused} />
    ),
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    CarStack,
    ExploreStack,
});
```

appNavigtor.js

```
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';
import SignIn from '../screens/SignIn'

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  // You could add another route here for authentication.
  // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
  SignIn: SignIn
}));
```

app.js

```
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <AppNavigator />
                </View>
            );
        }
}
```

I'm using expo i18n from 'i18n-js' and Localization from expo to translate the components, they work just fine. However I got bottomtabs generated by expo. I have no idea how to translate those tab labels I tried the library above, doesn't seem work.

the tabs look something like this

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/513

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to develop this:

I used the React-Native-i18n package. First:

```
npm install react-native-i18n --save
```

Then you need to create Localization files. Such as: en.json or fi.json

You should add the translations to those files:

en.json:

```
{
 "lang": "en",
   "button": {
     "ok": "OK",
     "cancel": "Cancel",
     "close": "Close"
   }
}
```

and

```
{
"lang": "fi",
  "button": {
    "ok": "OK",
    "cancel": "Peruuta",
    "close": "Sulje"
   }
}
```

You need to create i18n.js file.
Then in the MainTabNavigator.js:

```
import I18n from '../i18n'

ExploreStack.navigationOptions = () => ({
   tabBarLabel: I18n.t('button.ok'),
   tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      <MyTabBarIcon style={{width:22, height:21}} name={'explore'} focused ={focused} 
      />
  ),
});
```

I hope it helps you. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: This won't work as the tabBarLabel does not get updated when you change the language. You will need to send in some value that will trigger on language change in the bottomTabNavigation. https://medium.com/@leonlek/create-dynamic-language-changing-on-tabbarlabel-of-materialbottomtabnavigator-with-mobx-and-efc15bfbc1b3